# Flask: Function is not returning any String and getting Internal Server Error 500

Tags: python, pandas

I am returning a bunch of strings to Front End using Flask RESTful API. The string is generated after a ML algo runs on the input string and classify this to a predefined Answer. The back-end is in MongoDB.

The code given below was working fine earlier. Ever since I have inserted the following lines (marked as *) it is not returning any value. After debugging I found the error as `built-in error: The view function could not return a list`.

Below is my code (only relevant part)

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/response/',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def response():       

    if request.method=='POST':
        text_org = request.json['foo']
        text = json.loads(json.dumps(text_org))
        text = text.lower()
        if len(text.split())==0:
            return 'Please ask a question'
        elif len(text.split())<=3:
            resp = ' '.join(['What more would you like to know about', clean_text(text), '? Please be little more specific..']) 
            return resp
        else:
            df_to_match = pd.DataFrame({'Slot_Value':tbl_df['slot_value'],'User_In':[clean_text(text)]*len(tbl_df['slot_value'])})
            is_match = [process.extract(i, df_to_match['Slot_Value'], limit=3) for i in df_to_match['User_In']]
            is_match_ratio = [i for w in is_match for i in w]
            if list(is_match_ratio[0]).pop(1) > 65:
                #tup = [w for (w,i,n) in is_match_ratio]
                x = model.predict([text])
                x_t = le.inverse_transform(x) '# *new line
                x_t = x_t.tolist() '# *new line
                x_f = ' '.join(x_t)
                x_f = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9,]',' ',x_f)  # * new line
                y=x_f.replace(' ','').split(',')
                slot_value tbl_df.loc[tbl_df.Combi.str.contains(y),'slot_value']
                text_clean = clean_text(text) #User Defined Function for Text preprocessing
                df_exact = pd.DataFrame({'Slot_Value':slot_value,'User_input':[text_clean]*len(slot_value)})
                slot_exact = [process.extract(i, df_exact['Slot_Value'], limit=1) for i in df_exact['User_input']]
                slot_exact = ' '.join([n[0] for n in slot_exact[0]])
                for i in db_col.find({"slot_value":slot_exact},{"Answer":1,"_id":0}): # querying mongodb with only 'Answer' shall be retrieved
                    m = json.dumps(i).split('Answer',1)[-1] 
                    resp = m.replace('\\n','<br>').replace('"','').replace(':','').replace('}','')
                    resp_final = email_url(resp) # * new line
                    return resp_final
            else:
                resp = ' '.join(['Sorry I have not understood this, please rephrase the question or'])
                return resp
    else:
        resp = [random.choices(msg)]
        return resp



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("**Starting Server...")

app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5002, debug=True)
```

`email_url` is a UDF that performs some regex and return the variable `resp` with HTML tags. What I have figured out that all the exceptional cases like `text.split()<=3`, `' '.join(['Sorry I have not understood ..... '])` are working fine. So this means problem is with new lines as marked *, may be I am missing out anything?

> Edit: Few More Information

`le: LabelEncoder`
`model: MultinomialNB()`

The above model is used to predict the class for new input as received via `text_org = request.json['foo']`

Comment: Does anything else get printed out in the Flask console?

Comment: I am getting this message `POST http://locahost:5002/response/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 500)`. Upon clicking the above I am getting a list of `jquery.min.js:2`

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I the below line

```
slot_value tbl_df.loc[tbl_df.Combi.str.contains(y),'slot_value']
```

instead of `y` which is a `list`, I have changed it to `','.join(y)`

To enlighten others: `le.inverse_transform` always produce an array which needs to be converted to list. In the above code snippet `y` is that list. Hence such error was occurring.